# Rails add to routing get parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some action `signup` and I get this aighup url to template, but need add some get parametrs like this

```
http://localhost:3000/signup?list_id=1
```

I thing like this but not work

```
<%= link_to 'signup', signup_url('?id='@list.id) %>
```

my UserNotifierMailer

```
UserNotifierMailer.send_signup_email(params[:email], @list).deliver

def send_signup_email(email, list)
@list = list
mail( :to => email,
      :subject => 'Thanks for signing up for our amazing app' )
end
```

and I have template for my email

```
<h1>list id <%= @list.id %></h1>
<%= link_to 'signup', signup_url %>
```

but in url signup need add get params

Begin when user go to the signup url with get parameters need transfer this get parameters to action and in action check if exist get parameters - some logic

How to add get parameters to some routing in template or in action and transfer to template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to 'signup', signup_url(list_id: @list.id) %>
```

Comment: its work. How transfer this parameters to action when form in signup submit ?

Comment: now rhen sub,it form in signup in action, in params not find parameter list_id, hot to transfer this parameters with submit form ?

Comment: Here's some docs on the format of query strings (scroll to the bottom) http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to. In your controller you access them like you would any param. In @Codebeef's example it would be: `params[:list_id]`.  `list_id` is the name/key of the param and `@list.id` is the value being passed.